# SQL Oracle error ORA-06550,Encountered the symbol "SQLDEVBIND1Z_1"

Tags: sql, oracle, procedure, ora-06550

I have this very simple procedure in Oracle 18c that compiles just fine

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE quera_vcelar
(v_cislo_ula IN INFORMACIE_ULOV.cislo_ula%TYPE,
v_meno        OUT VARCHAR2,
v_bydlisko    OUT UDAJE_VCELAROV.bydlisko%TYPE)
IS
BEGIN
    SELECT meno || ' ' || priezvisko,bydlisko
        INTO v_meno,v_bydlisko
    FROM UDAJE_VCELAROV uv JOIN INFORMACIE_ULOV iu ON(uv.cislo_ula = iu.cislo_ula)
    WHERE iu.cislo_ula = v_cislo_ula;
END quera_vcelar;
/
```

But after I initialise the variables and try to run it

```
VARIABLE p_meno VARCHAR2(30)
VARIABLE p_bydlisko VARCHAR2(20)
EXECUTE quera_vcelar(10, :p_meno :p_bydlisko);
PRINT p_meno p_bydlisko;
```

I get this error

```
Error starting at line : 17 in command -
BEGIN quera_vcelar(10, :p_meno :p_bydlisko); END;
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 1, column 42:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SQLDEVBIND1Z_1" when expecting one of the following:

   . ( ) , * @ % & = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not rem =>
   <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
   like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset
The symbol "." was substituted for "SQLDEVBIND1Z_1" to continue.
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

I could not find any answer anywhere sadly.

Comment: there's no `SQLDEVBIND1Z_1` within the code.

Comment: Im sorry I dont understand wheres the problem @Barbaros Özhan

Comment: Isn't there a comma missing in your call `EXECUTE quera_vcelar(10, :p_meno, *,* :p_bydlisko);` ?

Comment: Thank you very much @wolφi that has solved it!

Comment: Excellent. I'll post it as an answer, which you can accept, to let other user see your question got answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is just a comma missing in your procedure call.

```
EXECUTE quera_vcelar(10, :p_meno  :p_bydlisko)  -- wrong
EXECUTE quera_vcelar(10, :p_meno, :p_bydlisko)  -- correct
```

It might well be that someone will close your question as it is only a typo. I hope it will stay open for a bit as I find the "SQLDEVBIND1Z_1" bit very spooky (as @Barbados has noticed as well). It seems to be a SQLcl feature to secure literals, but I need to read up more as I have never seen it before.